# Custom function for next / previous month in agenda view and the calendar

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm looking for a way to select `next` or `previous` month in both agenda view and the calendar.  I've written a concept/prototype function (below), but it doesn't calculate the `next` or `previous` months and I would also need to rewrite the function every month.

The date format for the `org-agenda-month-view` is different than the date format for `calendar-other-month`.  Further down below are some functions that are related to what I'm trying to accomplish -- e.g., calendar already has the ability to move forward or backward by month.

I think what may be needed is a function that identifies the month being viewed and then adds plus-or-minus one month (in the proper format) when hitting the `next` or `previous` button.

```
(defun lawlist-org-agenda-view-mode-dispatch ()
  "Select the month in agenda view."
  (interactive)
  (message "View: [7] JUL | [8] AUG | [9] SEP | [o]CT | [n]OV | [d]EC ")
  (let ((a (read-char-exclusive)))
    (case a
      (?7
        (org-agenda nil "a")
        (org-agenda-month-view 201307)
        (calendar)
        (calendar-other-month 7 2013)
        (lawlist-org-agenda-view-mode-dispatch))
      (?8
        (org-agenda nil "a")
        (org-agenda-month-view 201308)
        (calendar)
        (calendar-other-month 8 2013)
        (lawlist-org-agenda-view-mode-dispatch))
      (?9
        (org-agenda nil "a")
        (org-agenda-month-view 201309)
        (calendar)
        (calendar-other-month 9 2013)
        (lawlist-org-agenda-view-mode-dispatch))
      (?o
        (org-agenda nil "a")
        (org-agenda-month-view 201310)
        (calendar)
        (calendar-other-month 10 2013)
        (lawlist-org-agenda-view-mode-dispatch))
      (?n
        (org-agenda nil "a")
        (org-agenda-month-view 201311)
        (calendar)
        (calendar-other-month 11 2013)
        (lawlist-org-agenda-view-mode-dispatch))
      (?d
        (org-agenda nil "a")
        (org-agenda-month-view 201312)
        (calendar)
        (calendar-other-month 12 2013)
        (lawlist-org-agenda-view-mode-dispatch))
      (?q (message "Abort"))
      (otherwise (error "Either press \"q\" to quit, or select another option." )))))
```

---

Here are some related functions I've extracted from `cal-move.el` and `calendar.el`:

```
(defun calendar-other-month (month year &optional event)
  "Display a three-month calendar centered around MONTH and YEAR.
EVENT is an event like `last-nonmenu-event'."
  (interactive (let ((event (list last-nonmenu-event)))
                 (append (calendar-read-date 'noday) event)))
  (save-selected-window
    (and event
         (setq event (event-start event))
         (select-window (posn-window event)))
    (unless (and (= month displayed-month)
                 (= year displayed-year))
      (let ((old-date (calendar-cursor-to-date))
            (today (calendar-current-date)))
        (calendar-generate-window month year)
        (calendar-cursor-to-visible-date
         (cond
          ((calendar-date-is-visible-p old-date) old-date)
          ((calendar-date-is-visible-p today) today)
          (t (list month 1 year))))))))

;;;###cal-autoload
(defun calendar-forward-month (arg)
  "Move the cursor forward ARG months.
Movement is backward if ARG is negative."
  (interactive "p")
  (calendar-cursor-to-nearest-date)
  (let* ((cursor-date (calendar-cursor-to-date t))
         (month (calendar-extract-month cursor-date))
         (day (calendar-extract-day cursor-date))
         (year (calendar-extract-year cursor-date))
         (last (progn
                 (calendar-increment-month month year arg)
                 (calendar-last-day-of-month month year)))
         (day (min last day))
         ;; Put the new month on the screen, if needed, and go to the new date.
         (new-cursor-date (list month day year)))
    (if (not (calendar-date-is-visible-p new-cursor-date))
        (calendar-other-month month year))
    (calendar-cursor-to-visible-date new-cursor-date))
  (run-hooks 'calendar-move-hook))

;;;###cal-autoload
(defun calendar-backward-month (arg)
  "Move the cursor backward by ARG months.
Movement is forward if ARG is negative."
  (interactive "p")
  (calendar-forward-month (- arg)))

;;;###cal-autoload
(defun calendar-forward-year (arg)
  "Move the cursor forward by ARG years.
Movement is backward if ARG is negative."
  (interactive "p")
  (calendar-forward-month (* 12 arg)))

;;;###cal-autoload
(defun calendar-backward-year (arg)
  "Move the cursor backward ARG years.
Movement is forward is ARG is negative."
  (interactive "p")
  (calendar-forward-month (* -12 arg)))

;;;###cal-autoload
(defun calendar-scroll-left (&optional arg event)
  "Scroll the displayed calendar left by ARG months.
If ARG is negative the calendar is scrolled right.  Maintains the relative
position of the cursor with respect to the calendar as well as possible.
EVENT is an event like `last-nonmenu-event'."
  (interactive (list (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)
                     last-nonmenu-event))
  (unless arg (setq arg 1))
  (save-selected-window
    ;; Nil if called from menu-bar.
    (if (setq event (event-start event)) (select-window (posn-window event)))
    (calendar-cursor-to-nearest-date)
    (unless (zerop arg)
      (let ((old-date (calendar-cursor-to-date))
            (today (calendar-current-date))
            (month displayed-month)
            (year displayed-year))
        (calendar-increment-month month year arg)
        (calendar-generate-window month year)
        (calendar-cursor-to-visible-date
         (cond
          ((calendar-date-is-visible-p old-date) old-date)
          ((calendar-date-is-visible-p today) today)
          (t (list month 1 year))))))
    (run-hooks 'calendar-move-hook)))

(define-obsolete-function-alias
  'scroll-calendar-left 'calendar-scroll-left "23.1")

;;;###cal-autoload
(defun calendar-scroll-right (&optional arg event)
  "Scroll the displayed calendar window right by ARG months.
If ARG is negative the calendar is scrolled left.  Maintains the relative
position of the cursor with respect to the calendar as well as possible.
EVENT is an event like `last-nonmenu-event'."
  (interactive (list (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)
                     last-nonmenu-event))
  (calendar-scroll-left (- (or arg 1)) event))

(define-obsolete-function-alias
  'scroll-calendar-right 'calendar-scroll-right "23.1")
```

Comment: Please don't include the standard emacs sources in the question.
It adds unnecessary bloat.
Just list the names - they're findable in a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take:

```
(defvar lawlist-month)

(defun lawlist-org-agenda-view-mode-dispatch ()
  "Select the month in agenda view."
  (interactive)
  (message "View: [1-9] [o]CT [n]OV [d]EC, j(next), k(prev).")
  (let* ((a (read-char-exclusive))
         (month (case a
                  (?o 10)
                  (?n 11)
                  (?d 12)
                  (?j (or (and lawlist-month (mod (1+ lawlist-month) 12)) 1))
                  (?k (or (and lawlist-month (mod (1- lawlist-month) 12)) 1))
                  (t (and (> a ?0) (<= a ?9) (- a ?0))))))
    (if (setq lawlist-month month)
        (let ((year (nth 5 (decode-time (current-time)))))
           (org-agenda nil "a")
           (org-agenda-month-view
            (read (format "%d%02d" year month)))
           (calendar)
           (calendar-other-month month year)
           (lawlist-org-agenda-view-mode-dispatch))
      (message "Aborted"))))
```

It still misses some functionality like saving the window configuration and
recovering on abort.

#### UPD

The updated code can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/abo-abo/6044729).
I've added other years besides current, with support for j/k, as well as h/l for years.

Comment: Thank you so very much for this useful function.  Standard calendars all have this next/previous month feature.  Your function is something that would make a great addition to the standard org-mode release.  Your help is greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: You're welcome. I wouldn't mind contributing this to org-mode,
but I first have to send that letter to the FSF about signing off the rights.
They don't accept anything without it.

Comment: `Feature Request`:  Any possibility of expanding the function to include next / previous months for years other than the current year?  For example, when we reach December 2013, next brings us back again to January 2013 instead of advancing to the year 2014.  The scroll calendar right / left has that ability built in, so perhaps we could just read that month / year and pass its value over to your next / previous function, or whichever way works best for you would be fine.

Comment: `Observation`:  Also, if we are viewing November 2013 and press next, the agenda view and calendar jump to December 2012 instead of 2013.

Comment: AWESOME!  Thank you very much for revising the function and for posting it in the gist identified in your answer.  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: I use this function several times a day and it has become indispensable -- with the added revision in the `gist` cited above (and a few custom modifications here and there).  Just in case anyone is interested, I discovered today that the following code can be used in lieu of `org-agenda-month-view`, which saves a step and speeds up the display:  `(setq org-agenda-start-day (concat (format "%d" year) "-" (format "%02d" month) "-" "01"))`  .  It would precede `(org-agenda nil "a")`.  See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504673/how-to-decode-name-of-month-into-an-integer