# How to abort a function with an arrow key when using read-char-exclusive

Tags: emacs

Is there any way to abort a function with an arrow key when the function relies upon `read-char-exclusive`?

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to make Emacs think that the arrow keys are character keys.  If that behavior is problematic for any reasons, then perhaps the behavior could revert back to normal once the function ends by pressing an arrow key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to use `read-event` instead.

Character events are returned as the relevant integer, just like `read-char`.

Arrow keys are returned as symbols (`left`, `right`, `up`, `down`).

```el
(let ((event (read-event)))
  (cond ((characterp event)
         (message "Character: %s" (char-to-string event)))
        ((and (symbolp event) (memq event '(left right up down)))
         (message "Arrow key: %s" (symbol-name event)))
        (t
         (error "Unexpected event"))))
```

Comment: Yes, what @phils said. You can advise `read-char-exclusive`, but you have not given any reason to do that. Unless you have some special reason to use (a modified) `read-char-exclusive`, use `read-event` (or even perhaps `read-key`, depending on what you really need).

Comment: I am trying to modify a function written by @abo-abo in this gist:  https://gist.github.com/abo-abo/6044729  which was a follow-up to this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683821/custom-function-for-next-previous-month-in-agenda-view-and-the-calendar      Since the org-agenda buffer is selected with this function, the arrow keys would be really helpful to exit the function.  I'm trying now to use `read-event`, but am receiving the following error message:  `and: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, down`

Comment: lawlist: obviously because the symbol `down` has reached some code which was assuming a character value (characters are numbers). As per my example code, you need to handle the additional types that `read-event` can return.

Comment: Yes, that did it -- thank you very much -- greatly appreciated !!!!  In the @abo-abo function at issue, instead of using the format of `?` and a character (e.g., `(?O 10)`), I added four `(month (case a` conditions -- `('up 500)`, `('down 501)`, `('left 502)`, `('right 503)`.  And a slightly modified if/then/else -- `(if (not (and (setq lawlist-month month) (>= month 0) (<= month 12) ))`.