# How to use case and read-event with down-mouse-1

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a function that uses `(case (read-event) . . .)` -- I have been unable to get `down-mouse-1` to equal an integer for the duration of the function.  The following is an example where `down-mouse-1` yields a result of `Try again` instead of `Hello world`.  All of the following examples work, except for `down-mouse-1`: `('f12 516)`; `(?\s-k 517)`; `('f3 518)`; `('C-tab 519)`; `('C-M-s-right 520)`; `(?m 522)`.

```
(let* (
    (test (case (read-event)
      ('down-mouse-1 9999))))
  (cond
    ((eq test 9999)
      (message "Hello world."))
    (t (message "Try again."))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read-event` never returns `down-mouse-1`.  For a mouse click, the first event it will return will look like `(down-mouse-1 ...)`.  So you could do:

```
(pcase (read-event)
  (`(down-mouse-1 . ,_) 9999))
```

Note that in my experience, 99% of the uses of `read-event` would be better rewritten some other way.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear to me what you are trying to do.  But you should not quote the keys in a `case` clause.  E.g, use `down-mouse-1`, not `'down-mouse-1`.

Comment: Thank you -- the mouse appears to be a special animal -- the example by Stefan works.  However, I now need to figure out how to use the other keys with `pcase`.  I'll spend some more time trying to figure it out and then post another question if I can't get it.  Things like:   `('f1 1)`  `('right 503)`  `('return 505)`  `('escape 504)`  `('M-s-right 506)`  `('tab 511)`.  All of those work with `case`, but not `pcase`.

Comment: You don't need `pcase`.  All it is doing in Stefan's example is giving you pattern matching.  In that example, it is just testing the `car` for matching `down-mouse-1`.  `case` tests the same thing for each clause, which is not what you want here, but you can just use `cond`.  (You can also use `pcase`; I'm just saying that you do not need to.)

Comment: Ahhh....  It's all starting to make sense now -- i.e., remove `case`; use your suggestion of `car` (e.g., `(cond ((memq (car event) '(down-mouse-1 down-mouse-3)) . . .` ) and combine everything with the previous example by `phils` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084937/how-to-abort-a-function-with-an-arrow-key-when-using-read-char-exclusive   Thank you very much !!!