# How to decode name of month into an integer

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to write a function that will let me choose (interactively) the month and year for `org-agenda-month-view` -- which uses a format of `201312` (*without* double-quotes) for December 2013 .  I would like to use either words (`December`) or numbers (`12`) for the month, but need some assistance (please) to decode the name of the month into an integer -- something like `(if (not (integer-p month)) (setq month (decode-name-of-month month)))`.

Also, any pointers on how to consolidate my two `read-string`  `let` bindings into just one action would be greatly appreciated -- i.e., be able to manually input `January 2014` or `01 2014`; instead of first inputting `January` and then inputting `2014` in two separate actions.

```
(let* (
    (year (read-string "Insert the year: "))
    (month (read-string "Insert the month: ")))
  (org-agenda nil "1")
  (org-agenda-month-view (read (format "%s%02s" year month))))
```

---

**EDIT** (December 11, 2013):  First working draft based upon the helpful answers by @Drew and @Sean Perry.  Added variable `org-agenda-start-day`, which permits `(org-agenda nil "1")` to display [at the outset] the correct month based upon the user input -- the function `org-agenda-month-view` is no longer needed.  Updated variable `lawlist-parse-time-months` to fix a typo and include additional possibilities -- e.g., 01, 02, etc.

```
(defvar lawlist-parse-time-months '(
  ("1" . "01")
  ("01" . "01")
  ("jan" . "01")
  ("january" . "01")
  ("2" . "02")
  ("02" . "02")
  ("feb" . "02")
  ("february". "02")
  ("3" . "03")
  ("03" . "03")
  ("mar" . "03")
  ("march" . "03")
  ("4" . "04")
  ("04" . "04")
  ("apr" . "04")
  ("april" . "04")
  ("5" . "05")
  ("05" . "05")
  ("may" . "05")
  ("6" . "06")
  ("06" . "06")
  ("jun" . "06")
  ("june" . "06")
  ("7" . "07")
  ("07" . "07")
  ("jul" . "07")
  ("july" . "07")
  ("8" . "08")
  ("08" . "08")
  ("aug" . "08")
  ("august" . "08")
  ("9" . "09")
  ("09" . "09")
  ("sep" . "09")
  ("september" . "09")
  ("10" . "10")
  ("oct" . "10")
  ("october" . "10")
  ("11" . "11")
  ("nov" . "11")
  ("november" . "11")
  ("12" . "12")
  ("dec" . "12")
  ("december" . "12")))

(defun encode-name-of-month (month_name)
  (cdr (assoc (downcase month_name) lawlist-parse-time-months)) )

(defun decode-name-of-month (month)
  (car (rassoc month lawlist-parse-time-months)))

(defun foo (month year)
  (interactive
   (let* ((mon+yr  (split-string
                    (read-string "Month and year: " nil nil
                                 (format-time-string "%B %Y"(current-time)))
                    nil 'TRIM))
          (mon     (car mon+yr))
          (yr      (cadr mon+yr))
          (m2      (condition-case nil (format "%d" mon) (error nil))))
     (list (or m2 mon)  yr)))
  (setq org-agenda-start-day (concat year "-" (encode-name-of-month month) "-" "01"))
  (org-agenda nil "1") )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(require 'parse-time) ;; in standard lib
(defun encode-name-of-month (month_name)
  (cdr (assoc (downcase month_name) parse-time-months))
 )
(defun decode-name-of-month (month)
  (car (rassoc month parse-time-months))
 )
```

That should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun foo (month year)
  (interactive
   (let* ((mon+yr  (split-string
                    (read-string "Month and year: " nil nil
                                 (format-time-string "%B %Y"(current-time)))
                    nil 'TRIM))
          (mon     (car mon+yr))
          (yr      (cadr mon+yr))
          (m2      (condition-case nil (format "%d" mon) (error nil))))
     (list (or m2 mon)  yr)))
  (message "Month: %s, Year: %s" month year))

M-x foo 12 2013         ==> Month: 12, Year: 2013
M-x foo December 2013   ==> Month: December, Year: 2013
M-x foo Dec 2013        ==> Month: Dec, Year: 2013
M-x foo Nebraska 200000 ==> Month: Nebraska, Year: 200000
```

But you get the idea.  (Check for valid month names and month & year numbers.)

Comment: In a situation such as this (i.e, where answers from two or more people contributed to the solution), what is the politically correct way (please) to handle marking an answer?  Perhaps making a comment underneath both answers stating how each one was helpful, and then pick either one with a statement that "... due to forum limitations (i.e, of only being able to choose one of the various correct answers), this one was chosen ...." ?

Comment: @lawlist - Please give the credit to the user with fewer points. Thx.